# Ethernet with STM32 and ENC28J60

Tags: c, stm32, ping, ethernet, stm32h7

I'm trying to run **SPI Ethernet module **ENC28J60**** with **STM32H7**. I wrote some functions for ENC28J60 library. Now, I want to get ping from PC or Router, but I can not. If anyone can help me to run it, please answer this question.

After Ping, I want to access communication stm32 microcontrollers and ENC28J60. Unfortunately, I could not find suitable library and sample code.

Thanks,
Sajix

my .C file of ENC28J60:

```
#include "stm32_enc28j60.h"

extern SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;
static uint8_t Enc28_Bank;
uint8_t dataWatch8;
uint16_t dataWatch16;

//-> SPI Instruction Set
uint8_t ENC28_readOp(uint8_t oper, uint8_t addr){
    
    uint8_t spiData[2];
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI1_CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    spiData[0] = (oper| (addr & ADDR_MASK));
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, spiData, 1, 100);
    if(addr & 0x80)
    {
        HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, &spiData[1], 1, 100);
    }
    HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, &spiData[1], 1, 100);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI1_CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    
    return spiData[1];
}

void ENC28_writeOp(uint8_t oper, uint8_t addr, uint8_t data){
    
    uint8_t spiData[2];
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI1_CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    spiData[0] = (oper| (addr & ADDR_MASK));
    spiData[1] = data;
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, spiData, 2, 100);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI1_CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}

//-> Select Bank
void ENC28_setBank(uint8_t addr)
{
    if ((addr & BANK_MASK) != Enc28_Bank) 
    {
        ENC28_writeOp(ENC28_BIT_FIELD_CLR, ECON1, ECON1_BSEL1|ECON1_BSEL0);
        Enc28_Bank = addr & BANK_MASK;
        ENC28_writeOp(ENC28_BIT_FIELD_SET, ECON1, Enc28_Bank>>5);
    }
}

//-> Read & Write Control Registers
uint8_t ENC28_readReg8(uint8_t addr){
    
    ENC28_setBank(addr);
    return ENC28_readOp(ENC28_READ_CTRL_REG, addr);
}


void ENC28_writeReg8(uint8_t addr, uint8_t data){
    
    ENC28_setBank(addr);
    ENC28_writeOp(ENC28_WRITE_CTRL_REG, addr, data);
}

uint16_t ENC28_readReg16( uint8_t addr)
{
    return ENC28_readReg8(addr) + (ENC28_readReg8(addr+1) << 8);
}

void ENC28_writeReg16(uint8_t addrL, uint16_t data)
{
    ENC28_writeReg8(addrL, data);
    ENC28_writeReg8(addrL+1, data >> 8);
}

//-> Read & Write Buf

void ENC28_readBuf(uint16_t len, uint8_t* data)
{
    uint8_t spiData[2];
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI1_CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    spiData[0] = ENC28_READ_BUF_MEM;
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, spiData, 1, 100);
    for(uint16_t x = 1; x < len; ++x){
    HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, &spiData[1], 1, 100);
    };
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI1_CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}

void ENC28_writeBuf(uint16_t len, uint8_t* data)
{
    uint8_t spiData[2];
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI1_CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    spiData[0] = ENC28_WRITE_BUF_MEM;
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, spiData, 1, 100);
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, data, len, 100);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI1_CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}


//-> Read & Write PHY Registers
uint16_t ENC28_readPhy(uint8_t addr)
{
    ENC28_writeReg8(MIREGADR, addr);            // Pass the PHY address to the MII
    ENC28_writeReg8(MICMD, MICMD_MIIRD);           // Enable Read bit
    while (ENC28_readReg8(MISTAT) & MISTAT_BUSY);    // Poll for end of reading
    ENC28_writeReg8(MICMD, 0x00);                       // Disable MII Read
    return ENC28_readReg8(MIRD) + (ENC28_readReg8(MIRD+1) << 8);
}

void ENC28_writePhy(uint8_t addr, uint16_t data)
{
    ENC28_writeReg8(MIREGADR, addr);
    ENC28_writeReg8(MIWR, data);
    while (ENC28_readReg8(MISTAT) & MISTAT_BUSY);
}


//-> Initialization ENC28J60
void ENC28_Init(void)
{
    //uint8_t spiData[2];
    // (1): Disable the chip CS pin
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI1_CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_Delay(1);
    // (2): Perform soft reset to the ENC28J60 module
    ENC28_writeOp(ENC28_SOFT_RESET, 0, ENC28_SOFT_RESET);
    HAL_Delay(2);
    // (3): Wait untill Clock is ready
    while(!(ENC28_readOp(ENC28_READ_CTRL_REG, ESTAT) & ESTAT_CLKRDY));
    // (4): Initialise RX and TX buffer size
    ENC28_writeReg16(ERXST, RXSTART_INIT);
    ENC28_writeReg16(ERXND, RXSTOP_INIT);

    ENC28_writeReg16(ETXST, TXSTART_INIT);
  ENC28_writeReg16(ETXND, TXSTOP_INIT);
    
    ENC28_writeReg16(ERXRDPT, RXSTART_INIT);
    ENC28_writeReg16(ERXWRPT, RXSTART_INIT);
    
    
    
    // dataWatch16 = ENC28_readReg16(ERXND);
    
    // (5): Reviece buffer filters
    ENC28_writeReg8(ERXFCON, ERXFCON_UCEN|ERXFCON_ANDOR|ERXFCON_CRCEN);
    // ENC28_writeReg8(ERXFCON, ERXFCON_UCEN|ERXFCON_PMEN|ERXFCON_CRCEN|ERXFCON_BCEN);
    // dataWatch8 = ENC28_readReg8(ERXFCON);
    
    // (6): MAC Control Register 1
    ENC28_writeReg8(MACON1, MACON1_MARXEN|MACON1_TXPAUS|MACON1_RXPAUS|MACON1_PASSALL);
    // dataWatch8 = ENC28_readReg8(ERXFCON);
    
    // (7): MAC Control Register 3
    ENC28_writeOp(ENC28_BIT_FIELD_SET, MACON3,MACON3_PADCFG0|MACON3_TXCRCEN|MACON3_FRMLNEN);
    
    // (8): NON/Back to back gap
    ENC28_writeReg16(MAIPG, 0x0C12);  // NonBackToBack gap
    ENC28_writeReg8(MABBIPG, 0x12);  // BackToBack gap
    
    // (9): Set Maximum framelenght
    ENC28_writeReg16(MAMXFL, MAX_FRAMELEN); // Set Maximum frame length (any packet bigger will be discarded)
    
    // (10): Set the MAC address of the device
    ENC28_writeReg8(MAADR1, MAC_1);
    ENC28_writeReg8(MAADR2, MAC_2);
    ENC28_writeReg8(MAADR3, MAC_3);
    ENC28_writeReg8(MAADR4, MAC_4);
    ENC28_writeReg8(MAADR5, MAC_5);
    ENC28_writeReg8(MAADR6, MAC_6);
    
    dataWatch8 = ENC28_readReg8(MAADR1);
    dataWatch8 = ENC28_readReg8(MAADR2);
    dataWatch8 = ENC28_readReg8(MAADR3);
    dataWatch8 = ENC28_readReg8(MAADR4);
    dataWatch8 = ENC28_readReg8(MAADR5);
    dataWatch8 = ENC28_readReg8(MAADR6);
    
    if(dataWatch8==MAC_6)   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED1_GPIO_Port, LED1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

    
    //**********Advanced Initialisations************//
    // (1): Initialise PHY layer registers
    ENC28_writePhy(PHLCON, PHLCON_LED);
    ENC28_writePhy(PHCON2, PHCON2_HDLDIS);
    // (2): Enable Rx interrupt line
    ENC28_setBank(ECON1);
    ENC28_writeOp(ENC28_BIT_FIELD_SET, ECON1, ECON1_RXEN);
//  ENC28_writeOp(ENC28_BIT_FIELD_SET, EIE, EIE_INTIE|EIE_PKTIE);
//  ENC28_writeOp(ENC28_BIT_FIELD_SET, EIR, EIR_PKTIF);
}

//-> Transmitting & Recieving Packets
void ENC28_packetSend(uint16_t len, uint8_t* dataBuf)
{
    uint8_t retry = 0;
    
    while(1)
    {
        ENC28_writeOp(ENC28_BIT_FIELD_SET, ECON1, ECON1_TXRST);
    ENC28_writeOp(ENC28_BIT_FIELD_CLR, ECON1, ECON1_TXRST);
        ENC28_writeOp(ENC28_BIT_FIELD_CLR, EIR, EIR_TXERIF|EIR_TXIF);
        
        // prepare new transmission 
        if(retry == 0)
        {
            ENC28_writeReg16(EWRPT, TXSTART_INIT);
            ENC28_writeReg16(ETXND, TXSTART_INIT+len);
            ENC28_writeOp(ENC28_WRITE_BUF_MEM, 0, 0x00);  //line 485 enc28j60.cpp
            ENC28_writeBuf(len, dataBuf);
        }
        
        // initiate transmission
        ENC28_writeOp(ENC28_BIT_FIELD_SET, ECON1, ECON1_TXRTS);
        uint16_t count = 0;
        while ((ENC28_readReg8(EIR) & (EIR_TXIF | EIR_TXERIF)) == 0 && ++count < 1000U);
        if (!(ENC28_readReg8(EIR) & EIR_TXERIF) && count < 1000U) 
        {
       // no error; start new transmission
       break;
    }
        // cancel previous transmission if stuck
    ENC28_writeOp(ENC28_BIT_FIELD_CLR, ECON1, ECON1_TXRTS);
        break;
    }
}
```